# Can you have a variable that is both a Workbook and a String?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm unable to use the VLOOKUP function to search a wookbook that is a variable. One that changes name by date.

So I'm new to VBA and coding in general. Having a workbook that is a variable, according to date. Doing a VLOOKUP against that seems to be an issue. By reading online, it seems it can be done as a string, but it is already a workbook.

So bear in mind i've set wkbk as a variable (I've trimmed it down for this website, the variable searches for previous dates counting backwards from current date in a workbook named dd.mm.yyyy.xlsx and that part works fine).

```
Dim wkbk As Workbook

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
     "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-9]),"" "",VLOOKUP(RC[-9],'" & wkbk & "easy_form_response_list'!C1:C12,10))"
```

What I expected is a lookup of the workbook and sheet - what I get is a Run-time error '438'. Object doesn't support this property or method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need a string that is the fully formed and properly punctuated address to the external workbook's

```
Dim wkbk As Workbook, addr as string

SET wkbk = WORKBOOKS("THE_SOURCE_WORKBOOK.XLSX")

addr = wkbk.worksheets("easy_form_response_list").Range("A:L").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, External:=true)
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
   "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-9]), text(,), VLOOKUP(RC[-9], " & addr & ", 10))"
```

Are you sure you don't need this?

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
   "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-9]), text(,), VLOOKUP(RC[-9], " & addr & ", 10, FALSE))"
```

If you omit the optional fourth argument, your data needs to be sorted in an ascending manner.